# My mongodb connection stopped working and just loading into infinity and then I get a dissconnected error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Hello I have been trying to fix this for a week. It worked at first, but now it just stopped. I want to connect my vue app to a mongodb hosted by them and using this code

```
const express = require("express");
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    const gottenData = await doStuff();
    res.send(await gottenData.find({}).toArray());
});

async function doStuff() {
    console.log("connecting");
    const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(
        "mongodb+srv://<NAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.9tlzg.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewURLParser: true }
    );

    return client.db("database").collection("collection");
}

module.exports = router:
```

I am attaching screenshot of my mongodb setup as well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create a client and then .connect separately.

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    const gottenData = await doStuff();
    res.send(await gottenData.find({}).toArray());
});

async function doStuff() {
    console.log("connecting");
    const client = new mongodb.MongoClient('mongodb+srv://<NAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.9tlzg.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewURLParser: true });

    await client.connect();

    return client.db("database").collection("collection");
}

module.exports = router:
```

Edit: see this for docs https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/